# Permutation of numbers in a specific order.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How to calculate number of permutations from $1$ to $N$ such that for some $j$ these properties hold :
$$
P(i)>P(i-1)\;\;\; \
$$
$$
P(i) > P(i+1)\;\;\; \
$$
For $N=3$ it can be $(1,3,2)$ 
For $N=4$ it can be $(1,3,4,2)$.

Comment: Stated as it is, it is not possible for $N>3$. If you want to hold $P(i)>P(i-1)$ for any $i$, then, in particular, ti would hold for $i+1$ (as long as it is within the range). So you would have $P(i+1)>P(i)$, which contradicts the second inequality.
Please, give an example for $N=4$ what you are trying to get.

Comment: Depending on some interpretations, this is the number of weakly unimodal permutations, http://oeis.org/A000079 or the number of unimodal permutations, http://oeis.org/A011782

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is there a formula for these permutation ?

Comment: Did you look at those links, sam?

Comment: @GeryMyerson I did. But I couldn't get to  how to use the information there. It's so much information in there. I'm sorry. Could you please tell me how to use that ?

Comment: @GeryMyerson how are the sequences given there and the sequence I'm trying to find similar ? Can you give me an example. Also I don't know what unimodal permutation means. I'm not so good in mathematics. Please help me out.

Comment: @sam: I rejected your edit because I want to leave the extra material in the answer for future readers, and because the answer doesn’t actually give you the formula: it just points you in the right direction.

Comment: I wasn't notified of your comments, sam, because you spelled my name wrong. "unimodal" means having a single local maximum, which is exactly what you want, right? rises to a maximum, then falls away? But if you're "not so good in mathematics", why are you interested in a problem like this one? If it's homework for some course you're enrolled in, I'd suggest asking your teacher for help, as that's her job (and also asking her for permission to post questions to the net).

Answer (score 0):

HINT: If, as [your later question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998949/permutation-of-n-numbers-with-middle-element-as-greatest) suggests, you require that $2\le j\le N-1$, then you are trying to count the permutations of $\{1,\ldots,N\}$ that increase from position $1$ to a maximum at some position $j<N$ and then decrease to position $N$.

It never hurts to collect some numerical data. For $N=3$ there are just $2$ acceptable permutations, $\langle 1,3,2\rangle$ and $\langle 2,3,1\rangle$, since the $3$ clearly has to go in the middle. What about $N=4$? We must have the $4$ in position $2$ or position $3$. If it’s in position $2$, we can have $\langle 1,4,3,2\rangle$, $\langle 2,4,3,1\rangle$, or $\langle 3,4,2,1\rangle$, and if it’s in position $3$, we can have $\langle 1,2,4,3\rangle$, $\langle 1,3,4,2\rangle$, or $\langle 2,3,4,1\rangle$.

For $N=5$ the maximum of $5$ must be in position $2,3$, or $4$, but instead of counting the possibilities for those positions separately, let’s see if we can find a way to count them all at once. We’ll have to put $1,2$, or $3$ of the other $4$ numbers before the $5$. Say we decide to put the $1$ and $3$ before the $5$ and the $2$ and $4$ after it; do we have any further choice in how we arrange these numbers? No: the once before the $5$ must be in increasing order, and the ones after the $5$ must be in decreasing order, so that we get the permutation $\langle 1,3,5,4,2\rangle$. Once we decide which numbers go before the $5$, **we’ve completely determined the permutation**: those numbers must be arranged in increasing order, and the remaining numbers, the ones that go after the $5$, must be arranged in decreasing order. We can put any non-empty proper subset of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ before the $5$: non-empty, since we require at least one number before the $5$, and proper, because we need to leave at least one number to go after the $5$. The set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ has $4$ elements, so it has $2^4$ subsets. One of those subsets, however, is the empty set, and another is the whole set $\{1,2,3,4\}$; we can’t use either of those as the set of numbers before the $5$, so we’re left with $2^4-2=14$ subsets that we *can* use, and they give rise to the following $14$ permutations:

$$\begin{align*}
&\langle 1,5,4,3,2\rangle,\langle 2,5,4,3,1\rangle,\langle 3,5,4,2,1\rangle,\langle 4,5,3,2,1\rangle,\\
&\langle 1,2,5,4,3\rangle,\langle 1,3,5,4,2\rangle,\langle 1,4,5,3,2\rangle,\langle 2,3,5,4,1\rangle,\langle 2,4,5,3,1\rangle,\langle 3,4,5,2,1\rangle,\\
&\langle 1,2,3,5,4\rangle,\langle 1,2,4,5,3\rangle,\langle 1,3,4,5,2\rangle,\langle 2,3,4,5,1\rangle
\end{align*}$$

Now try to generalize the reasoning that I just employed in the case $N=5$ to get a formula for the number of acceptable permutations in terms of $N$.