# Permutation of N numbers with middle element as greatest.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many ways are there to place N numbers so that

`P(i-1) > P(i)`

`& P(i)> P(i+1) where i is the middle element`.

Eg -  N=3 : (1,3,2) , (2,3,1)

Comment: Place the greatest element, then place the second then the third. In how many ways can you do each of these steps?

Comment: @Sophie Can you elaborate please ? And how many ways are there to do this exactly ?

Comment: How does $(1,3,2)$ satisfy this? If $P(1)=1, P(2)=3, P(3)=2$, then $P(i-1)>P(i)>P(i+1)$ does **not** hold!

Comment: Which is the middle of a four-element list?

Comment: @5xum sorry there was a mistake in problem statement.

Comment: @StevenGregory I have updated problem statement.

Comment: @sam: The current version of the problem statement contradicts both the title and the example: it requires the permutation to be decreasing, so that for $N=3$ the only permutation satisfying it is $\langle 3,2,1\rangle$. Do want a $j$ with $2\le j\le N-1$ such that $P(i)<P(i+1)$ when $1\le i<j$, and $P(i)>P(i+1)$ when $j\le i<N$? That would give you a permutation that increases from position $1$ to position $j$ and then decreases to position $N$.

Comment: In fact, isn’t this intended to be a duplicate of [your earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998929/permutation-of-numbers-in-a-specific-order)?